# UnionFS read from first priority branch, write to all branches

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there a UnionFS configuration that allows me to merge two RW-directories, so that I can read from the higher-priority directory if a requested file exists in there (normal behaviour), but changes to the merged directory are written to both of the branches?

If not, is there a comparable filesystem (e.g. MergerFS, OverlayFS, AUFS etc.) that allows me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK none of the "union filesystems" support multiple write targets.

What are you trying to accomplish ultimately?

edit:

Wouldn't it be safer / simpler to use something like rsync? Lots of people already do what you're looking for with rclone mounts or other network filesystems and simply have a regular rsync or rclone sync to the remove storage.

MergerFS' docs include some examples for creating such caches.

https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#caching

Comment: I would like to create a UnionFS mount with a local directory and a directory that's mounted from a remote server. Everything that I'd write to that directory would be on my local drive, but also backed up remotely to that server and I could read either from my local drive, or (after I for example deleted the file due to space limitations on my local drive) from the remote server. It would, in essence, be a very simple file-based cache.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/755033/trapexit) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/755087/trapexit). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: I did think about using a separate program to transfer the data and that's probably the way I'm going, but I would have preferred the filesystem to handle it because I want the data to be backed up immediately and doing that with separate program necessitates watching the relevant folders (with e.g. inotifywait) for changes, which I'd prefer not to due to its inconsistency over different (FUSE) mount types.

But it seems that I'll go in this direction and hack something together that hopefully works well enough.